# How change PDFVerion by iTextSharp 5.5.9 lib?

Tags: itext

I using iTextSharp version 5.5.9

My PDF file is version 1.7,

I try using `Writer.SetPdfVersion` or `Writer.PdfVersion` to set PDF Version is 1.6

But result output still is version 1.7

My code bellow:

```
 public void SetPDFVer(string parm_strFile,string parm_strOutputFile )
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(parm_strFile);         
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(parm_strOutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
                {               
                    stamper.Writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_6);
                   // stamper.Writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6;

                }
            }
        }
```

How can change version PDF from 1.7 to 1.6?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `PdfStamper` you cannot *decrease* the version using

```
stamper.Writer.SetPdfVersion
```

This allows only *increasing* it.

If you need to *decrease* it, this can only be done with a different `PdfStamper` constructor:

```
new PdfStamper(reader, fs, PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6)
```